# Center widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning to use Kivy, so I walked through the Pong tutorial and started messing around with the code. So, I removed everything but the bouncing ball and decided to generate multiple balls on demand. The problem I am having is that while I can place balls where I want them when application is already running (for example, adding a ball on touch works fine), but when I add balls in the app build() they don't get placed right. Here is the code I have. The balls placed on touch, correctly start from the center. But the ball added in build() starts from the lower left corner. Why? I wanted to add more moving widgets with different properties, but I cannot seem to figure out how to place them on application start.

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<World>:
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.center
            size: 10, 10

<Agent>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

```
from random import randint

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


class World(Widget):
    agents = ListProperty()

    def add(self):
        agent = Agent()
        agent.center = self.center
        agent.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
        self.agents.append(agent)
        self.add_widget(agent)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.add()

    def update(self, dt):
        for agent in self.agents:
            agent.move()
            if agent.y < 0 or agent.top > self.height:
                agent.velocity_y *= -1
            if agent.x < 0 or agent.right > self.width:
                agent.velocity_x *= -1


class Agent(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class WorldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        world = World()
        # add one ball by default
        world.add()
        Clock.schedule_interval(world.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return world


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorldApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. The default widget size is 100, 100. By the time I add the initial ball, the World widget is not rendered and therefore has a default size. But it is possible to pass the windows size in the Widget constructor. So changing the World instantiation to

```
world = World(size=Window.size)
```

solved the problem

Comment: If you have to initialize more complex widgets at start time, widgets that usually won't have the properties when created, you can use kivy Clock to schedule a callback method, where you will initialize all your settings, the clock will execute the method after the kivy program has finished initializing the whole gui, this way you will get updated parameters and attributes.